# differentiating and setting two different types of css and jsp for pc Version and iPad Version

Tags: web, ipad

I am trying to make an existing website to properly shown in iPad as an extended support. As there will be two sets of jsp and CSS for both version.

How can I differentiate when website is accessed by ordinary PC browser or iPad browser and what kind of approach should I take so that I can set different JSP and CSS for both version?

Please provide useful resources to reference. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for my case, I check the user agent whether it is coming from `iPad` user agent . Then I use two sets of css or necessary jsp.